# Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) -

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qwebengine, qtwebengine

Получаю вот такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

поискав в интернете, нашел что из-за двойного освобождения памяти, долго искав где я это делаю, я решил полностью закоментировать все деструкторы по очереди что бы найти где ошибка, но после того как я их все закоментировал, ошибка дале продолжает вылазить, потом присмотрелся, а там путь не к моему файлу, ошибка не у меня в коде, а в исходиках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нет других ответов, то отвечу то что мне помогло. В итоге, у меня была проблема, что я удалял объект из памяти, но в итоге указатель указывал туда же, и в деструкторе я делал проверку на NULL, которая при удаленном объекте давала истину. В итоге после удаления просто установил указатель на NULL

```
delete pointer;
pointer = NULL;
```